# Delete the non-duplicate row from actual Database Table in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table variable `@Temp` and a database table `Master`.

This is sample data in both tables:

`@Temp`:

```
EMPID      ID
1           1
1           3
2           2
2           3
```

`Master`:

```
EMPID     ID
1          1
1          2
1          3
2          1
2          2
2          3
3          1
3          2
```

Now I have to delete rows from `Master` table where the pair of EMPID & ID is not matched from `@temp` table. It should delete 2 rows (for which the pair does not exists in the @Temp table). I also want to keep such records whose EMPID doesn't exists in the @Temp table. After deleting the records my Master table should have below records.

**OUTPUT**

```
Master

EMPID      ID

1          1
1          3
2          2
2          3
3          1
3          2
```

Comment: I dunno if this works in sqlserver, but it may help : delete from master where id not in ( select id from @temp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
DELETE FROM Master WHERE EMPID IN (SELECT EMPID FROM @Temp) AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM @Temp WHERE EMPID=Master.EMPID AND ID = Master.ID)
```

mark it as answer if it helps

Comment: can you please explain that what is your expected result, which records should be deleted?

Comment: I have updated the answer, let me know if this doesn't work for you